# How do I apply my copyright information from XMP automatically with DigiKam?

Tags: software, metadata, xmp

I have an xmp file with my copyright information provided by the [Creative Commons license wizard](http://creativecommons.org/choose/). How can I configure DigiKam to automatically apply this information to every image I import?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the metadata templates for this purpose, but the digiKam documentation is not exactly clear on this.

According to section 2.4.3 of the [digiKam Handbook](http://www.digikam.org/docs):

> At the very least,
>   for all images that will be exported and/or published in any form, the authorship and copyright
>   information should be part of their metadata. Nothing more simple to do with digiKam: you can
>   setup the default identity, and any images ingested be digiKam will be automatically informed.

I believe this is referring to the metadata templates which you can define by opening digiKam then selecting the "Settings" menu, then "Configure digiKam". In the window that appears, select the "Templates" icon from the scrolling menu on the left. You should now see the "Metadata templates" page of digiKam's settings, and you can define copyright and author information here. There are also tabs for "Location", "Contact" and "Subjects" but I don't know why you would want these values to be appended to all imported images.

I recommend you run some tests to check that you get the result you want with a few test images, before going ahead with a mass import of your image library.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the way that templates are implemented in digiKam requires a separate template for every combination of copyright, location, and contact information.  Applying a template will overwrite all 3 types of information, even if it is blank in the template or exists already in the file.  Since this is the case, I have written an Exiftool script for myself that I can run on a directory to set the copyright information, and a separate ExifTool script that sets the contact information.

Answer (score -1):

1. As the other answer already said, add a copyright metadata template in Settings.
2. After import mark all images in the folder and then
3. go to metadata/tags sidebar and add the information you want
4. OR open the batch manager (ctrl-B) and apply your metadata there.

I do not know whether you can do it directly on import. It might be possible.